# Delete information from two join tables in MySQL using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

HTML

```
echo "<a href=\"delete.php?id=".$row{'idHeroes'}."\">Delete</a>";
```

PHP

```
$joinTables = "DELETE * FROM heroes,stats WHERE idHeroes = $_GET[id]";
mysql_query($joinTables);
header('Location: index.php');
```

When I click the button it refreshes the page but nothing happens.

//I found a solution

```
$deleteHeroes = "DELETE FROM heroes WHERE idHeroes = '".$_GET['id']."'";
    $deleteStats = "DELETE FROM stats WHERE idStats = '".$_GET['id']."'";
    mysql_query($deleteHeroes);
    mysql_query($deleteStats);
```

Comment: you found solution ? :) , its my solution in my comments.

Comment: yeah I upvoted your comment thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rewrite your query like that:

```
  $joinTables = "DELETE * FROM heroes
                 INNER JOIN  stats WHERE 
                 WHERE heroes.idHeroes= stats.idHeroes 
                 and heroes.idHeroes = '".$_GET['id']."' ";
```

OBS. you have to escape your variable before using it in your query or someone will delete all your columns :) .

this is bad idea to delete from GET .

Comment: still the same issue, refreshes the page but nothing is deleted.

Comment: try echo `$_GET['id']` and see if there is value.

Comment: I did it with die and it gets the id

Comment: try just one table like that: `DELETE * FROM heroes WHERE idHeroes = '".$_GET['id']."' `